# check & validate table containing similar values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table called businessname (id, name) and I need to insert data into this table but before that I need to check for similar name is existing in the table. this table called similarwords display below.

```
id | words
===============================
 1 | transport, travel
-------------------------------
 2 | IT, information technology
-------------------------------
 3 | builders, contractors
-------------------------------
```

As example-> If there is business name called "ABCD transport" when user try to insert "ABCD travel" it should validate & give error message "Similar name already exists." is there way to do this in SQL ?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: I'm using sql version 15.0

Comment: Short answer - not easily. You will need to write some complicated code to find "similarities". Have you considered misspellings or transpositions as well? How about different languages? Using a table that is not properly normalized is usually not a good starting point.

Comment: @user_5939667 . . . Look into full text search.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a procedure like this to insert data -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DATA_INSERT (@ID INT, @NAME VARCHAR(100))
AS BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM BUSINESSMAN WHERE NAME = @NAME)
  BEGIN
    PRINT ('Similar name already exists')
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
   INSERT INTO BUSINESSMAN VALUES (@ID, @NAME)
  END
END

EXEC DATA_INSERT 4,'ABCD TRANSPORT'
```

Although I will suggest you to create an primary key on that column if you doesn't want duplicates to be inserted.

Comment: I think you didn't get the question. I need to insert data into businessname, but before that user need to validate it. to contain similar words. if name called "ABCD transport" exists, user should not be able to insert name called "ABCD travel".